# TRying to set up face book sdk

Tags: android

I'm trying to install the face book sdk and have all the projects showing up under my Package explore
Every project has almost evreyline of code as being a error.

I think the problem is that all the inports 
except import java.io.InvalidObjectException; and import com.facebook.internal.Validate

have a error that says the import (name of inport) cannot be resolved.  This is for both java sdk and android sdk.

I'm assuming if this is fixed all the remiaing errors will go away.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

right click your project -> properties -> java compiler

select enable project specific , and select compiler comp level to 1.6

Perhaps this thread will help:

[Android Facebook SDK import occurs with errors - Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713333/android-facebook-sdk-import-occurs-with-errors-eclipse)

Comment: Hi,Did not work, becouse it was allready set at 1.6, but thank you for trying to help.