# The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\workspace\FacebookSDK\bin\facebooksdk.jar'

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, dependencies

I've been stuck on this for over two days. I've looked at all the other similar questions and tried implementing their answers. Nothing works. I've cleaned and built projects so many times to no avail. I've added libraries, deleted libraries... Can someone please solve this for me?

I'm trying to use Facebook SDK for my project in Eclipse. I imported the Facebook SDK library as existing Android code. That worked fine. Then I created a new Android application project, went to its properties, and added the Facebook SDK. Then I get the red exclamation mark on the project screen:

[image]

The `Problems View` says this:

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\workspace\FacebookSDK\bin\facebooksdk.jar'
```

And then I checked the Java build path libraries and this error came up:

[image]

It says facebooksdk.jar is missing. Am I supposed to add it somewhere? Where is the jar located?

How do I fix this?

**EDIT** Buiding FacebookSDK before adding it to project. Many errors:

[image]

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Loader<SimpleGraphObjectCursor<T>> cannot be resolved to a type GraphObjectPagingLoader.java    /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 119    Java Problem
Loader<SimpleGraphObjectCursor<T>> cannot be resolved to a type GraphObjectPagingLoader.java    /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 109    Java Problem
The method onStartLoading() of type GraphObjectPagingLoader<T> must override or implement a supertype method    GraphObjectPagingLoader.java    /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 118    Java Problem
The import android.support cannot be resolved   FacebookFragment.java   /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 21 Java Problem
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   FacebookFragment.java   /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 42 Java Problem
The method deliverResult(SimpleGraphObjectCursor<T>) of type GraphObjectPagingLoader<T> must override or implement a supertype method   GraphObjectPagingLoader.java    /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 104    Java Problem
The method onActivityCreated(Bundle) of type FacebookFragment must override or implement a supertype method FacebookFragment.java   /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 47 Java Problem
...
...
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 253    Java Problem
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   FacebookDialog.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 341    Java Problem
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   FacebookDialog.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 327    Java Problem
The method getString(int) is undefined for the type PickerFragment<T>   PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 568    Java Problem
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   FacebookDialog.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 324    Java Problem
The method getLoaderManager() is undefined for the type PickerFragment<T>.LoadingStrategy   PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 883    Java Problem
LoaderManager cannot be resolved to a type  PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 884    Java Problem
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   FacebookDialog.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 320    Java Problem
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 55 Java Problem
The import android.support cannot be resolved   PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 26 Java Problem
The import android.support cannot be resolved   PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 25 Java Problem
The import android.support cannot be resolved   PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 24 Java Problem
Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")    WebDialog.java  /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 402    Java Problem
The method getActivity() is undefined for the type PickerFragment<T>    PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 187    Java Problem
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 185    Java Problem
The method onActivityCreated(Bundle) of type PickerFragment<T> must override or implement a supertype method    PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 184    Java Problem
The method onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) of type PickerFragment<T> must override or implement a supertype method  PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 153    Java Problem
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 133    Java Problem
The method onInflate(Activity, AttributeSet, Bundle) of type PickerFragment<T> must override or implement a supertype method    PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 132    Java Problem
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 120    Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type PickerFragment<T> must override or implement a supertype method PickerFragment.java /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook/widget    line 119    Java Problem
LocalBroadcastManager cannot be resolved to a type  BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java  /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook   line 25 Java Problem
The import android.support cannot be resolved   BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java  /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook   line 8  Java Problem
LocalBroadcastManager cannot be resolved to a type  BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java  /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook   line 30 Java Problem
LocalBroadcastManager cannot be resolved    BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java  /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook   line 25 Java Problem
LocalBroadcastManager cannot be resolved    BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java  /FacebookSDK/src/com/facebook   line 30 Java Problem
```

**Compiler version**

[image]

Comment: Did you build the Facebook SDK before adding it to another project? As it seems that Facebook sdk jar file is missing.

Comment: no because when I build the Facebook SDK it gives me hundreds of errors. So First I add the SDK. Create a new project. Then add the SDK to the project. Then clean and build

Comment: So you don't have the jar file inside the bin folder and that's the issue.

Comment: do you know where I can find that jar file? is it located somewhere else in my project? maybe the android-support.jar?

Comment: the bin folder is empty. Why isn't the facebooksdk.jar file there?

Comment: Can you accept the answer if that solved your issue..

Comment: It still hasn't been solved. I do not know why the jar file is not there. I will check out that last link you provided and see if it helps solve this issue.

Comment: There is still an error unfortunately. The compiler is on level 1.6 and it has not improved the situation. I still get a red exclamation point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `facebooksdk.jar` is missing. The jar file is present in the `PROJECT_FOLDER/bin/facebooksdk.jar`, in this case it should be here: `FacebookSDK/bin/facebooksdk.jar`. This file is created when you build your project.

So, the solution is to build the `FacebookSDK project` and then clean this project `AndroidFB6`.

Comment: I will try that. So I assume I need to build FacebookSDK project before I add its library to AndroidDB6? Maybe I should just create a new project...

Comment: Yes. do you get any errors when you build FacebookSDK project?

Comment: These are the compilation errors. Which version did you use to compile the FacebookSDK project? Did you try to change the version? Go to: properties -> Java Compiler -> Java Compliance and change here (try to change it to 1.6).

Comment: And I added an image of the compiler version that you can look at. It appears to be on version 1.6

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713333/android-facebook-sdk-import-occurs-with-errors-eclipse