# Facebook SDK v.4 for Android: errors on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, configuration, sdk

I am trying to import the latest version (4.0.1) of the Facebook Android SDK into eclipse but I am facing issues in having the project being properly built and imported as a Library.

I followed the steps (for android studio, ported to Eclipse) provided in the official guide and looked through Google for other developers having the same problems as I am having but I am still not able to have it properly working.

Here are the steps I do:

1. Download the Facebook SDK for android from here: https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip
2. Extract the projects
3. In Eclipse, import existing Android code into workspace
4. Select the folder "facebook" and choose the only project that is shown (the project is properly imported)
5. Right click on "facebook" project, properties, android and check "isLibrary"
6. clean project

At this point I still have issues for annotations and classes not found from "android.support" package.

Project's setting for Java compiler is "1.6", minSDK is 9 and target is 17.

I tried also to add the facebook library to my main project but it is still not working.

I tried to put java 1.7 in the compiler but it is not resolving the missing classes plus it is saying that to compile with java 1.7 I need to have min API set to kitkat (which I don't want because I will not be able to compile for 4.2 and 4.3).

I added manually the androd support jar from the SDK Manager folder of android and this resolved partially the missing classes but some did remain.

I am using Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) with JDK 1.7.0_51 and the latest ADT Plugin (all android components updated with SDK Manager).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention that working with version 3.x seems fine (and this is probably one of the first questions about v.4 since I cannot find anything on the web that is related to Facebook for Android SDK v.4)

Comment: possible duplicate of [android facebook sdk v4.0 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302087/android-facebook-sdk-v4-0-not-working)

Comment: New android sdk uses gradle so you cant import it as usual android project. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302087/android-facebook-sdk-v4-0-not-working and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some more tests and find out that by downloading the two libraries:

android-support-v4.jar
bolts-android-1.1.2.jar

from the github project (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) did the trick.

So the steps are the following:

1. Download, unpack and import as android existing code into workspace the latest v.4 version of the Facebook SDK for Android.
2. Download the two jars from GitHub
3. Set the Facebook Project as "isLibrary"
4. Add the two jars as "external jars" in the classpath
5. Set the java compiler to 1.7
6. clean and rebuild the project

Now errors are gone.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the facebook sdk from [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk).
2. Extract the zip file.
3. Import only facebook sdk project into eclipse as "Existing Android code into 
   workspace".
4. Now, this project will show many errors, do not open any java file or 
   resource file and do not try to do any imports or clean project until I 
   mention it to do so.
5. First add the v7 library to this project by doing right click on facebook 
   sdk project >> properties>>android>>Add Library.(If you don't  have latest 
   v7 support library download it from sdk manager), also set the project build 
   target to the maximum android version available and select "is library".
6. Now, right click on facebook project and select >Build path>Configure build 
   path>Libraries tab>Add external jars> browse to place where you extracted 
   facebook sdk in step 2 and find two jar files in libs folder(android-
   support-v4.jar and bolts-android-1.1.2.jar) and add both files. Switch to 
   "order and export" tab and select both the jar files and click on ok.
7. Now right click on facebook sdk >>properties>>Java Complier>>set the 
   "compiler compliance level to 1.7 or more and use default compliance settings.
8. Now select the project and click on Project > Clean.

This should remove all errors now. This is how it worked for me.

Comment: @m.v.n.kalyani great :)

Answer (score 0):

[Android Facebook SDK import occurs with errors - Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713333/android-facebook-sdk-import-occurs-with-errors-eclipse)

Check this out. May be this will help you.
I faced same problem while working in Android Studio.
But you are facing in Eclipse.

Comment: I already tried to change the compiler level and it is already 1.6 by default on that project. Still not working