# Facebook SDK 4.8.2 import in ECLIPSE

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

How to import facebook sdk 4.8.2 in eclipse. I am unable to import as facebook folder contains aar file when we directly download developer site. And from git , unable to get src files of facebook

Comment: go through this link you will got solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks but latest facebook sdk contains facebook folder which has aar file which cannot be imported.

Comment: The Latest SDK is in gradle structure. I think we have to use android studio. So may be we can't use latest sdk for eclipse IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have an answer from [Android Facebook SDK 4 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse)

> I also have faced this problem, so I will write a short guide, how to
>   install it in Eclipse.
>
> ## Step 1. Import to Eclipse
>
> First of all, download the [latest
>   version](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip) of SDK (on current moment it is 4.0). Unzip it to a
>   folder.
>
> Open Eclipse, click the right mouse button in `"PackageExplorer"` and
>   choose `"Import"`. After that, go to `"Android"` -> `"Existing Android
>   Code Into Workspace"`.
>
> [image]
>
> Now click `"Browse"` and choose unzipped SDK folder, and deselect all
>   other found projects, except from the `"facebook"` (it is an SDK).
>   Other included projects are just samples, and you don't need them now.
>
> [image]
>
> You may select "copy project to workspace" checkbox, if you need this.
>
> ## Step 2. Fixing errors
>
> After importing, we will see, that the
>   whole facebook SDK package are in errors:
>
> [image]
>
> But if we look closer, and open one of marked as error classes, we
>   will find, that SDK tried to import`support.v4 library`:
>
> [image]
>
> It required for properly compilation. You can find instructions how to
>   download it using `Android SDK Manager`[here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).
>
> After it downloading, you can find it in your Android sdk folder:
>   `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v4`. Then add it to the facebook SDK
>   project: right mouse click on SDK project -> `"Properties"` -> `"Java
>   Build Path"` -> `"Libraries"` -> `"Add External JARs"`, and choose
>   `android-support-v4.jar` from it's folder.
>
> [image] [image]
>   [image]
>
> After that a lot of errors will be gone:
>
> [image]
>
> But, there are other errors. So we are going to another class, and
>   found it error code piece. Move mouse pointer on it, and Eclipse will
>   show you the hint, of what kind of error you are facing. It says that
>   your compliance Java must be version 1.7. Allow Eclipse do it by
>   clicking "`Change project ..."`, or do it manually by going to
>   `"Properties"` -> `"Java Complier"` -> `"Compiler compilance level"`
>   -> `"1.7"`.
>
> [image]
>
> OR
>
> [image]
>
> Moving ahead. Now we are facing only one kind of error, that says that
>   the FB SDK can't find required Bolts Android library.
>
> [image]
>
> We are going to google, found it compiled jar in a [repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.parse.bolts/bolts-android).
>   Choose the latest version (for current moment it's 1.2.0, but SDK
>   gradle file is using 1.1.4, so you may choose that), and download the
>   jar. Now add it to the facebook SDK as external lib, as we do it
>   before.
>
> [image]
>
> Voila! Ther are no errors anymore!
>
> [image]
>
> Also don't forget to set in the facebook SDK project `"Properties"` ->
>   `"Android"`, that it is a Library.
>
> [image]
>
> Just for ensurance, close/re-open the SDK project and clean it
>   (`"Eclipse menu"` -> `"Project"` -> `"Clean"`), so all files can build
>   properly.
>
> ## Step 3. Add it to the Android project
>
> Now you can try to add
>   it to your Android app. Go to your Android app project `"Properties"`
>   -> `"Android"` -> `"Library"` -> `"Add"`, and choose facebook SDK.
>
> [image]
>
> Follow [official tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/), and set up your Android application
>   project (don't forget to add all required elements to Manifest.xml).
>   Than you can use [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3) to add LoginButton to your
>   Activity. Try to build it. It should run without problem.
>
> [image]

This also might be helpful, if you find any issue: [Facebook SDK v.4 for Android: errors on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514591/facebook-sdk-v-4-for-android-errors-on-eclipse)

Check also: [Android Facebook SDK configuration on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945618/android-facebook-sdk-configuration-on-eclipse)

Hope it help

---

**EDIT:** As you would see in the comments below, this answer is not already corrected. The best way to deal with this problem is export project from `Eclipse` to `Android Studio`, which doesn't have this issue and becoming the first Android Developer tool, where Eclipse seems to be as was said on Android Dev Summit 2015 truly deprecated.

Comment: Thanks but latest facebook sdk contains facebook folder which has aar file which cannot be imported

Comment: Maybe this would be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417419/how-to-convert-aar-to-jar

Comment: On last Android Dev Summit 2015 was announced that Eclipse is deprecated. Try to import your Eclipse project to Android Studio or you would face more and more Eclipse ADK issues

Comment: The Latest SDK is in gradle structure. I think we have to use android studio. So may be we can't use latest sdk for eclipse IDE

Comment: You said: Gradle structure. Next argument to use Android Studio ;-)

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have to migrate my project. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still procrastinating migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio. And I found that the last version that works with Eclipse would be Facebook Android SDK 4.5.1. Download link here: https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=facebook-android-sdk-4.5.1.zip

Following this instructions make it work!

Comment: Both Eclipse and Facebook SUCK. This errors are unacceptable. Great answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! I'm still procrastinating migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio. And I found that the last version that works with Eclipse would be Facebook Android SDK 4.5.1. Download link here: https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=facebook-android-sdk-4.5.1.zip

Following this instructions make it work!